# Using Silex without a vhost and Apache

Tags: symfony, apache2, silex

I am setting up my first Silex project using Fabien's skeleton on Github:
https://github.com/fabpot/Silex-Skeleton

For some reason I can't create a vhost for this project, the silex project stays in a sub directory.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/my/example.com/htdocs/myapp/
      ../src/app.php
      ../cache
      ../config
      ../templates
      ../vendor
      ../web/index.php
```

I want to access my app through the URL :
http://example.com/myapp/hello/Fabien/

I have created a `.htaccess` file in htdocs/myapp

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /myapp
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ web/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I have urls like
http://example.com/myapp/index.php/hello/Fabien/

How can I get rid of the index.php?

Comment: Could you try with `RewriteBase /myapp/web` ?

Comment: Thanx, much better! :-) The Url is now http://example.com/myapp/web/hello/Fabien. Any chance to get rid of the "web" as well?

Comment: The recommended way of doing this is setting `web` to be your webroot.

Comment: @AdrienBrault, do you want to add your answer as an "answer" in the sense of stackoverflow, so that I can mark it as "correct" and you get some credits for it? Igorw, thanks, changing the document root in a local .htaccess file is not allowed in this specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `RewriteBase` directive to `/myapp/web`:

```
RewriteBase /myapp/web
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: you can run Silex with php built-in web server, w/o Apache at all. That's handy to quick-start hacking / prototyping in your local development environment. composer.json of Fabien's skeleton contains instructions to start local web server. You can do that by executing `composer run` in the project directory.

The limitation of this approach is that composer will stop the server in 300 seconds. To avoid that - you should execute following command directly: `php -S localhost:8888 -t web web/index_dev.php`. Hello page will be available at http://localhost:8888/hello/Fabien/.